# Is Audience in Google Adwords can use Destination URL using the API?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I know that basically Audience (Remarketing \ User Lists \ Interest Lists \ Any other name...) don't have a Destenation URLs.
With that I have notice that I can update the URL of the criteria which warrpe the Audience.
Then when I get the Criteria_Performance_Report I see the URL I've updated.

Now, My question is, If an ad is triggered with this audience will it get the Ad destination URL or the Criteria destination URL.

Thanks for taking the time to help.
R.g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audiences do support unique destination URLs, and you can see/edit them in the AdWords web interface by showing the "Destination URL" column.  You can set them via the API as well as you've seen, and they should serve correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I think I checked it when I start using it. Either they add it later or I missed it some way.